# Mininet-wifi Cannot import name OVSKernelAP with Python

Tags: python, sdn, mininet

I am building a SDN network using Mininet-Wifi and I have this smallnetwork as a test just to learn more about Python, so I this code to run

```
!/usr/bin/python

from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.node import Controller, RemoteController, OVSKernelAP
from mininet.link import TCLink
from mininet.cli import CLI
from mininet.log import setLogLevel

def topology():

"Create a network."
net = Mininet( controller=Controller, link=TCLink, accessPoint=OVSKernelAP )

print "*** Creating nodes"
h1 = net.addHost( 'h1', mac='00:00:00:00:00:01', ip='10.0.0.1/8' )
h2 = net.addHost( 'h2', mac='00:00:00:00:00:11', ip='10.0.1.1/8' )

sta1 = net.addStation( 'sta1', mac='00:00:00:00:00:02', ip='10.0.0.2/8', position='50,50,0' )
sta2 = net.addStation( 'sta2', mac='00:00:00:00:00:03', ip='10.0.0.3/8', position='40,50,0')
sta3 = net.addStation( 'sta3', mac='00:00:00:00:00:04', ip='10.0.0.4/8', position='20,50,0' )

ap1 = net.addAccessPoint( 'ap1', ssid= 'new-ssid', mode= 'g', channel= '5', 
position='25,50,0', range='35' )
ap2 = net.addAccessPoint( 'ap2', ssid= 'new-ssid', mode= 'g', channel= '5', 
position='75,50,0', range='35' )

c1 = net.addController( 'c1' )

s1 = net.addSwitch('s1')

#net.runAlternativeModule('../module/mac80211_hwsim.ko')

print "*** Configuring wifi nodes"
net.configureWifiNodes()

print "*** Associating and Creating links"

net.addLink(ap1, s1)
net.addLink(ap2, s1)
net.addLink(s1, c1)
#net.addLink(ap1, ap2)

net.addLink(s1, h1)
net.addLink(s1, h2)

net.addLink(ap1, sta1)
net.addLink(ap1, sta2)
net.addLink(ap1, sta3)

print "*** Starting network"
net.build()
c1.start()
ap1.start( [c1] )
ap2.start( [c1] )

"""uncomment to plot graph"""
net.plotGraph(max_x=100, max_y=100)

net.startMobility(startTime=0)
net.mobility(sta1, 'start', time=1, position='0.0,50.0,0.0')
net.mobility(sta1, 'stop', time=30, position='100.0,50.0,0.0')
net.stopMobility(stopTime=31)

print "*** Running CLI"
CLI( net )

print "*** Stopping network"
net.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
setLogLevel( 'info' )
topology()
```

And after runing "sudo mn --custom test.py" (My file name is test.py ) I get the error.

Caught Excepcion. Cleaning up... ImportError: cannot import name OVSKernelAP

What Can i do? I have mininet and mininet-wifi already installed.

Answer (score 1):

The main source of your error is in lines 3 to 7. With Mininet-wifi you just need to import the following:

```
from mininet.log import setLogLevel, info
from mn_wifi import CLI
from mn_wifi import Mininet_wifi
```

That's all you need to import. You might have a few more errors such as the minimum range of your access points should be 116m and s1 and ap1 will have the same DPID so you should change s1 to s3